# nginx ssl 400 error(The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port)

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-config

my certificates is valid
there is another webServer in my ec2 and use 443 port.
so I planed use 8443 port rather then 443 port.
but Ive got 400 error

I think the ssl what I typed in my config isn't work well in the url.
ssl absolute path also not working.

would you help me?

this is my config.

NGINX.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  access_log off;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and
/etc/nginx/conf.d/myTest.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 8443 default ssl;
  server_name ;

  ssl_certificate star_cyberskyshop_com_NginX_cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key star_cyberskyshop_com_NginX_nopass_key.pem;

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
    root /var/www/code/img1/public;
    Index index.html index.htm index.php;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/code/img1/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  }
}
```

this is curl log

```
jangbyeongwoo@jangbyeong-uui-MacBookAir ~ % curl -v https://img1.cyberskyshop.com:8443/sample.jpg
*   Trying 52.78.41.24:8443...
* Connected to (52.78.41.24) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=KR; L=Seoul; O=Cybersky Co., Ltd.; OU=Development Team; CN=*.e-skyshop.com
*  start date: Mar 26 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match img1.cyberskyshop.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'img1.cyberskyshop.com'
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'img1.cyberskyshop.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

below picture is i added ssl pem file.
it's CN is present well(*.cyberskyshop.com). but curl log isnt show correct one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIm4t.png)

Comment: cert invalid, try: `curl -k -v https://img1.cyberskyshop.com:8443/sample.jpg`

Comment: @num8er hi. i typed correct ssl files. but it shows diffrents one that run on my ec2 server.

Comment: I suspect You have defined certificate for wildcard in `star_cyberskyshop_com_NginX_cert.pem` . But it should be bundle of 3 files (CAA, CA Root, Your cert concatenated in one file). http://joxi.ru/KAxggxUZPapV28

Comment: now Your url gives bad gateway, fix Your php fpm config to make socket file to be correct or fix nginx `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;` to be same as in fpm www.conf

Comment: @num8er there are 4 information in the "star_cyberskyshop_com_NginX_cert.pem;" and it shows correct SSL Information. you can see the screenshot in my post(almost end area)

Comment: @num8er i think www.conf's sock information and fastcgi_pass sock is same. www.conf : "listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock"

Comment: then, try to restart php-fpm, then check if socket exists: `ls -la /run/php-fpm`, if not, then there is permission errors to solve. Try to set `/run/php/php-fpm.sock`

Comment: @num8er thanks. but its not work. you know why certificates are mismatch?? i am really wonder.  this is part of my certificates` Subject: C=KR, ST=Seoul, O=CyberSky Co., Ltd., CN=*.cyberskyshop.com ` i think i use 443 port another project so it shows mismatch. but when i connect to 8443 port, it shows there is no SSL. even i set ssl certificates in my nginx.conf. its driving me crazy..

Comment: it was ALB issus. thanks.